# Does anyone know how to solve this non-homogeneous linear partial differential equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I would like to solve the following pde:
\begin{align}
\left(-\frac{x}{\alpha}+ \beta y\, G_1(y)\right)\frac{\partial R}{\partial y} + \left(\eta y\right)\frac{\partial R}{\partial x}   = \gamma\, G_2(y)\,R,
\label{eq}
\end{align}

where $G_1$, $G_2$ are just functions of $y$ and $R=R(x,y)$. Basically, I am having some problems to deal with the crossing terms (by crossing term I mean $y\partial_x R$, for example). My first attempt was to apply the method of characteristics. But I was not successful so far. Then, I tried to apply the following procedure. The previous equation can be rewritten as
\begin{align}
\left(A(x,y),\eta y\right)\cdot \nabla_{x,y}R  = -C(y)\,R,
\end{align}

where $A(x,y)\equiv-\frac{x}{\alpha}+ \beta y\, G_1(y)$, and $-C(y) \equiv\gamma\, G_2(y)$. That means $R$ should be a exponential function like
\begin{align}
R = U(x,y)e^{V(x,y)}
\end{align}

By applying this in the original pde, one gets
\begin{align}
\left(A(x,y) \frac{1}{U}\frac{\partial U}{\partial y} + \eta y\frac{1}{U}\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}\right) + \left(A(x,y) \frac{1}{V}\frac{\partial V}{\partial y} + \eta y\frac{1}{V}\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}\right) = -C(y)
\end{align}

However, the crossing terms persist. Does anyone have any clue on how to proceed?